# How to code "If only one variable exist" in a search 'algorithm'?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am employing a DIY grid search 'algorithm' which starts at the top left and ends at the bottom right. My 'algorithm' can only travel RIGHT and DOWN, it looks at its neighbors and see which is the smallest and moves to the smallest. If both neighbors are equal it priorities going DOWN. Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

# Create grid with random integers from 0 to 9
width, height = 10, 10
np.random.seed(0)
grid = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(width, height))

# Agent actions
goal = grid[-1][-1] # Row, Column

# Check mechanism
print(grid)
print(goal)
```

```
def rightdown():
    x, y = 0, 0
    current_pos = grid[x][y]
    steps = [grid[0][0]]
    print("Initial pos: ", current_pos)
    
    
    for i in range(16): 
        if grid[x + 1][y] < grid[x][y + 1]: # Go Right
            current_pos = grid[x + 1][y]
            
            x += 1
            
        elif grid[x + 1][y] > grid[x][y + 1]: # Go Down
            current_pos =  grid[x][y + 1]
            
            y += 1
            
        elif grid[x + 1][y] == grid[x][y + 1]: # Go Down if same
            current_pos = grid[x][y + 1]
    
            x += 1
           
        elif grid[0][9] or grid[1][9] or grid[2][9] or grid[3][9] or grid [4][9] or grid [5][9] or grid [6][9] or grid [7][9] or grid [8][9] or grid [9][9]:
            print('right hit')
            
        elif grid[9][0] or grid[9][1] or grid[9][2] or grid[9][3] or grid [9][4] or grid [9][5] or grid [9][6] or grid [9][7] or grid [9][8] or grid [9][9]:
            print('bott hit')
        
        print('Current position: ', current_pos)
        print('This is x, y: ', x, ',', y, '\n')    
        
        steps.append(current_pos)

    
    print('Total steps taken: ', sum(steps))
        
        
rightdown()
```

My question is: I want to make it so that once it reaches the end of the array (Ex. Right), it will only go down. However how do I code this? In english, this would mean that if only the right array exist, move down instead of if both right and down exist.

EDIT_1: I edited the code to see if the counter position reaches either the bottom row or the far right column, however the following code is now giving an error:

> index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10

To bypass this change the range from 16 to 15 or less. 16 was used because it is iterating to the next number.

> for i in range(15):

Why doesn't the following code print 'right hit' when it is at the following position [6][9]?

Comment: Compare `x` and `y` to `width` and `height`, maybe?

Comment: Sorry @TigerhawkT3, I don't follow, what do you mean by that?

Comment: `x` and `y` are the current values, representing your location when walking through the grid. `width` and `height` are the max values, representing the dimensions of the grid. If the current values reach the max, then you've hit the end of the grid in that direction.

Comment: I looked into adding a new elif statement: 'elif grid[x][-y]:', however it doesn't ever get to this condition and I have no idea why. So I edited it for certain values but still doesnt   fulfill the condition. Any idea why? My code above reflects what I've done.

Comment: width = 10, indexes are 0...9 . you can only go right if x+1 will be still smaller then width - if x+1 == 10 you get an index error on nexts checks.

Comment: I see, however ignore the index error for now, I want to know why when the range is 15, why doesnt this program print 'right hit' when it reaches [6][9]?

Comment: `elif grid[0][9] or grid[1][9] or grid[2][9] or grid[3][9] or grid [4][9] or grid [5][9] or grid [6][9] or grid [7][9] or grid [8][9] or grid [9][9]:` i snot doing what you think it does. That checks if any value under that cooord is Truthy (!=0) you need to check `if x==9: print("right hit")` and `ìf y==9: print("bottom hit")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several pecularities in your code:

- you need to keep your indexes in check so they do not try to access outside of your given array
- you need to check if you can advance indexes or go out of bounds when moving
- the only time to compare values under the index is when deciding where to move next: `elif grid[0][9] or grid[1][9] ....  or grid [9][9]: print('right hit')` accesses values and checks if any is not truthy - it does not check indexpositions
- the `sum of steps()` will sum up all visited values, not count steps (might be intentional)

You could fix it up like so:

```
def rightdown(g):
    row, column, (max_row, max_column) = 0, 0, g.shape

    print(g)
    last_pos = -1,-1
    current_pos = row,column
    current_value = g[row][column]
    steps = [current_value]

    def p(): #  printer function called twice later: dry - don't repeat yourself
        msg = "hit bottom" if row+1 == max_row else (
            "hit right" if column+1 == max_column else "")
        print("Pos:", current_pos, "  Value:", g[row][column], msg)
      
    while current_pos != (max_row - 1, max_column - 1):
        p()
        if row+1 < max_row and column+1 < max_column:
            vd = g[row + 1][column]
            vr = g[row][column + 1]

            if vd <= vr:
                row += 1
            else:
                column += 1
        elif row+1 == max_row:
            column += 1
        elif column+1 == max_column:
            row += 1

        steps.append(g[row][column])
        last_pos, current_pos = current_pos, (row, column)

    p()
    print('Steps', steps, 'taken: ', len(steps), "sum:", sum(steps))
```

Call it with:

```
import numpy as np
import random

# Create grid with random integers from 0 to 9
width, height = 10, 10
np.random.seed(0)
grid = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(width, height))
print(grid)

rightdown(grid)
```

Output:

```
[[5 0 3 3 7 9 3 5 2 4]
 [7 6 8 8 1 6 7 7 8 1]
 [5 9 8 9 4 3 0 3 5 0]
 [2 3 8 1 3 3 3 7 0 1]
 [9 9 0 4 7 3 2 7 2 0]
 [0 4 5 5 6 8 4 1 4 9]
 [8 1 1 7 9 9 3 6 7 2]
 [0 3 5 9 4 4 6 4 4 3]
 [4 4 8 4 3 7 5 5 0 1]
 [5 9 3 0 5 0 1 2 4 2]]
Pos: (0, 0)   Value: 5
Pos: (0, 1)   Value: 0
Pos: (0, 2)   Value: 3
Pos: (0, 3)   Value: 3
Pos: (0, 4)   Value: 7
Pos: (1, 4)   Value: 1
Pos: (2, 4)   Value: 4
Pos: (3, 4)   Value: 3
Pos: (3, 5)   Value: 3
Pos: (4, 5)   Value: 3
Pos: (4, 6)   Value: 2
Pos: (5, 6)   Value: 4
Pos: (5, 7)   Value: 1
Pos: (5, 8)   Value: 4
Pos: (6, 8)   Value: 7
Pos: (6, 9)   Value: 2 hit right
Pos: (7, 9)   Value: 3 hit right
Pos: (8, 9)   Value: 1 hit right
Pos: (9, 9)   Value: 2 hit bottom
Steps [5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 7, 2, 3, 1, 2] taken: 19 sum: 58
```